# Obtain EventID from URL

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api

The URL to my calendar Event was successfully constructed/encoded using this logic:

```
// Get the event URL using the CalendarApp event's ID
var ati = calendar.getId().indexOf("@");
var splitEventId = newEvent.getId().split('@');
var EventId = Utilities.base64Encode(splitEventId[0] + " " + calendar.getId().substring(0, ati + 2)).replace(/=/gi, '');
var eventUrl = "https://calendar.google.com/calendar/u/0/r/eventedit/" + EventId;
```

In another script, I now want to obtain/log the original Event ID.
So i need to decode the existing eventUrl in the same way.
I tried this:

```
var eventIdEncoded = eventUrl.split("/").pop(); // Get the encoded part from the URL
    try {
      eventIdEncoded = eventIdEncoded.replace(/-/g, '+').replace(/_/g, '/'); // Revert URL-safe Base64 encoding
      eventIdEncoded += "==".substring(0, 2 - eventIdEncoded.length % 2); // Add padding if needed
      var eventIdDecoded = Utilities.base64Decode(eventIdEncoded);
      
      // Convert the decoded byte array to a string
      var eventId = Utilities.newBlob(eventIdDecoded).getDataAsString();
      Logger.log("Decoded Event ID: " + eventId);
```

But my obtained Event ID appears to be a too-long-looking string of digits, with an "@g" at the end, so I'm 99% sure it didn't work correctly.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `eventId` that you get gives you the eventID and Calendar ID(the one with the @g at the end). To get the `eventId` only, I added `split` on your script.

`// Convert the decoded byte array to a string`

`var eventId = Utilities.newBlob(eventIdDecoded).getDataAsString(); Logger.log("Decoded Event ID: " + eventId);`

`var decodeEventId = eventId.split(" ")[0]; Logger.log(decodeEventId);`

**Reference:**

- [split](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp)

Comment: Feel free to ask if you have any questions with respect to the answer posted above.

Comment: Thanks! Simpler to solve than I thought haha.

Comment: @LionelHutz You're welcome. It is as your code is correct it just needs a few tweaks to achieve the goal.